# Spring Session results in spam: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jboss, session-variables

I'm new to Spring and Java. I'm trying to setup session management using Sprint Session but I'm getting error spam on the server. I followed this guide:

https://www.javainuse.com/spring/springboot_session

My setup is slightly different. I'm using JBoss with an Oracle database. In my application.properties I used JNDI instead of putting my database credentials in there:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name = java:jboss/OracleDatabaseInstance

spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.session.timeout.seconds=900
```

I also excluded the MySQL stuff from pom.xml since I am using Oracle. Otherwise all my source is identical to the guide.

When I tried to run the code I just get a white page. The server admin contacted me and said he is getting this spam on the server about every minute:

```
Caused by: Error : 942, Position : 12, Sql = DELETE FROM SPRING_SESSION WHERE EXPIRY_TIME < :1 , OriginalSql = DELETE FROM SPRING_SESSION WHERE EXPIRY_TIME < ?,
Error Msg = ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
......................
2023-08-10 06:28:00,012 ERROR [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler] (pool-30-thread-1) Unexpected error occurred in scheduled t
ask: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [DELETE FROM SPRING_SESSION WHERE EXPIRY_TIME < ?]; nested exce
ption is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: I don't know anything about tool you use, but - error says that you established connection to Oracle schema and tried to delete row(s) from SPRING_SESSION table, but that particular user doesn't own table with that name. Or, if it isn't supposed to have it, there's no (public?) synonym or a view with that name available to that user (but that's probably less likely). Therefore: connect to that user and verify whether table exists or not. Oracle says it doesn't.

Comment: It doesn't exist, but spring session is supposed to create it. I think you're barking up the right tree though. I'm going to fiddle around with the synonyms and grants and see if that's what's going on.

I may have to make deploy the tables on my own instead of using spring.

Comment: Have a look in application logs. It must be an error entry when trying to create the spring session specific tables when application starts. Also, you should remove the `spring.h2.console.enabled` setting from your configuration file. It just creates confusion because you are not connecting to an H2 database.